# Exception in thread "main" com.couchbase.client.core.config.ConfigurationException: Could not open bucket

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I am getting below error while working with Couchbase enterprise java client.

Exception in thread "main"

```
com.couchbase.client.core.config.ConfigurationException: Could not open bucket.
    at com.couchbase.client.core.config.DefaultConfigurationProvider$6.call(DefaultConfigurationProvider.java:296)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.config.DefaultConfigurationProvider$6.call(DefaultConfigurationProvider.java:293)


Caused by: com.couchbase.client.core.CouchbaseException: Could not parse configuration
    at com.couchbase.client.core.config.parser.BucketConfigParser.parse(BucketConfigParser.java:63)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.config.loader.AbstractLoader$1.call(AbstractLoader.java:186)


Caused by: com.couchbase.client.deps.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of com.couchbase.client.core.config.BucketCapabilities from String value ("durableWrite"): value not one of declared Enum instance names: [nodesExt, dcp, cbhello, xattr, couchapi, cccp, touch, xdcrCheckpointing]
 at [Source: {"name":"example","uuid":"9016c8efe8dc06a9c464d6122d4bae73","bucketType":"membase","authType":"sasl","uri":"/pools/default/buckets/example?bucket_uuid=9016c8efe8dc06a9c464d6122d4bae73","streamingUri":"/pools/default/bucketsStreaming/example?bucket_uuid=9016c8efe8dc06a9c464d6122d4bae73","localRandomKeyUri":"/pools/default/buckets/example/localRandomKey","controllers":{"compactAll":"/pools/default/buckets/example/controller/compactBucket","compactDB":"/pools/default/buckets/example/controller/compactDatabases","purgeDeletes":"/pools/default/buckets/example/controller/unsafePurgeBucket","startRecovery":"/pools/default/buckets/example/controller/startRecovery"},"nodes":[{"couchApiBaseHTTPS":"https://127.0.0.1:18092/example%2B9016c8efe8dc06a9c464d6122d4bae73","couchApiBase":"http://127.0.0.1:8092/example%2B9016c8efe8dc06a9c464d6122d4bae73","systemStats":{"cpu_utilization_rate":51.94902548725637,"cpu_stolen_rate":0,"swap_total":20114640896,"swap_used":14524493824,"mem_total":17027633152,"mem_free":7918469120,"mem_limit":17027633152,"cpu_cores_available":4},"interestingStats":{"cmd_get":0,"couch_docs_actual_disk_size":98733017,"couch_docs_data_size":65024155,"couch_spatial_data_size":0,"couch_spatial_disk_size":0,"couch_views_actual_disk_size":759929,"couch_views_data_size":787685,"curr_items":39482,"curr_items_tot":39482,"ep_bg_fetched":0,"get_hits":0,"mem_used":160451400,"ops":0,"vb_active_num_non_resident":0,"vb_replica_curr_items":0},"uptime":"149337","memoryTotal":17027633152,"memoryFree":7918469120,"mcdMemoryReserved":12991,"mcdMemoryAllocated":12991,"replication":0,"clusterMembership":"active","recoveryType":"none","status":"healthy","otpNode":"ns_1@127.0.0.1","thisNode":true,"hostname":"127.0.0.1:8091","nodeUUID":"fc910ff6899bf9d42abf4f43345a7611","clusterCompatibility":393221,"version":"6.5.0-4960-enterprise","os":"win64","cpuCount":4,"ports":{"direct":11210,"httpsCAPI":18092,"httpsMgmt":18091,"distTCP":21100,"distTLS":21150},"services":["cbas","eventing","fts","index","kv","n1ql"],"nodeEncryption":false,"configuredHostname":"127.0.0.1:8091","addressFamily":"inet","externalListeners":[{"afamily":"inet","nodeEncryption":false},{"afamily":"inet6","nodeEncryption":false}]}],"stats":{"uri":"/pools/default/buckets/example/stats","directoryURI":"/pools/default/buckets/example/statsDirectory","nodeStatsListURI":"/pools/default/buckets/example/nodes"},"nodeLocator":"vbucket","saslPassword":"5fa44be3a06c28e4cf8491852234b77f","ddocs":{"uri":"/pools/default/buckets/example/ddocs"},"replicaIndex":false,"autoCompactionSettings":false,"vBucketServerMap":{"hashAlgorithm":"CRC","numReplicas":1,"serverList":["127.0.0.1:11210"],"vBucketMap":[[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1]]},"maxTTL":0,"compressionMode":"passive","replicaNumber":1,"threadsNumber":3,"quota":{"ram":9203351552,"rawRAM":9203351552},"basicStats":{"quotaPercentUsed":0.3595628376578611,"opsPerSec":0,"diskFetches":0,"itemCount":0,"diskUsed":12887754,"dataUsed":4241408,"memUsed":33091832,"vbActiveNumNonResident":0},"evictionPolicy":"valueOnly","conflictResolutionType":"seqno","bucketCapabilitiesVer":"","bucketCapabilities":["durableWrite","couchapi","dcp","cbhello","touch","cccp","xdcrCheckpointing","nodesExt","xattr"]}; line: 1, column: 10260] (through reference chain: com.couchbase.client.core.config.DefaultCouchbaseBucketConfig["bucketCapabilities"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException.from(InvalidFormatException.java:74)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.weirdStringException(DeserializationContext.java:1022)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.EnumDeserializer._deserializeAltString(EnumDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.EnumDeserializer.deserialize(EnumDeserializer.java:96)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:287)
```

Comment: Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create("127.0.0.1");
  cluster.authenticate("admin", "admin1234");
  Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket("example");

Comment: This seems to be the relevant error: `Caused by: com.couchbase.client.deps.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of com.couchbase.client.core.config.BucketCapabilities from String value ("durableWrite"): value not one of declared Enum instance names: [nodesExt, dcp, cbhello, xattr, couchapi, cccp, touch, xdcrCheckpointing]`.

Comment: While deserializing some XML, the value of `durableWrite` is not an expected value of the enum [`BucketCapabilities`](https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-core-io-1.5.8/com/couchbase/client/core/config/BucketCapabilities.html).

Comment: Hi, I'm a Couchbase SDK developer.  Could you let me know what version of the SDK and the server you're using please?  Also if you're starting new development, it's best to do it with our new Java 3.x release.

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>com.couchbase.client</groupId>
   <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.5</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: After changing to 3.0.2 it's working fine.
@GrahamPople I need to use collection in couchbase. when i try to hit from postman to to create a scope, it's not allowing me to create the scope.
can you please help me for the same.

http://localhost:8091/pools/default/buckets/company/collections

Not allowed on this version of cluster

Comment: @LokeshG you probably need to enable the developer preview mode - please see this blog post for details https://blog.couchbase.com/introducing-collections-developer-preview-in-couchbase-server-6-5/

Comment: Or downgrade couchbase to 5.1.1 (which works with older client versions)